# MPI_TYPE_CREATE_HVECTOR

Tags: c, mpi

How is `MPI_Type_create-hvector` stored in the memory?

I wanna send a column using `MPI_Send` and i think it's better to define new type using `MPI_Type_create-hvector`!!!!

but i don't know it's a good way or not, and how?

denote that i wrote a c program.

Comment: You may use the simpler `MPI_Type_vector` for sending regular columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [the Open MPI documentation](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.0/man3/MPI_Type_create_hvector.3.php):

```
int MPI_Type_create_hvector(int count, int blocklength,
    MPI_Aint stride, MPI_Datatype oldtype, MPI_Datatype *newtype)
```

It's not very clear from your question what exactly you are trying to do. Note that when you create this datatype, you decide exactly how your vector is stored in memory.

So if you have a contiguous chunk of `double`s that are accessed in a row-major 2D-esque manner (i.e. `data[iCol+N_COLS*iRow]`), then you can create a "column" datatype in the following manner.

```
MPI_Datatype mpiColumn;
int info = MPI_Type_create_hvector(N_ROWS, 1, sizeof(double)*N_COLS, MPI_DOUBLE, &mpiColumn);
```

As noted in the comments, this example can alternatively be done using `MPI_Type_vector()` instead:

```
MPI_Datatype mpiColumn;
int info = MPI_Type_vector(N_ROWS, 1, N_COLS, MPI_DOUBLE, &mpiColumn);
```

Comment: please enlarge about it, i'm beginner in mpi and couldn't undrestand how is `MPI_Type_create-hvector` stored in memory?

Comment: "MPI_Type_create_hvector" is not stored in memory. You have an array that is stored in memory. Then you create an MPI datatype that allows you to reference your specific data with MPI send/recvs in a manner convenient to you. My example was just one example of how it can be used.

Comment: thanks. could you help me about it's better using vector or hvector?

Comment: Usually you use vector, unless you need hvector. The only difference is that the input variable `stride` means "stride in doubles" for vector, but means "stride in bytes" for hvector.

Comment: Just nitpicking, but it is actually called Open MPI with a space :)

Comment: @HristoIliev We'll just pretend that was a typo, and not me doing too much shared-memory programming...